# Reading google calendar events

Tags: ios, calendar, google-calendar-api

My client has created a calendar which is private. He provided ClientId, Secret, and Google Server API Key.

He says it is possible to read events using auth, but I can't find a way. I created my own public calendar and reading events and was successful, but when I made it private it was not working.

Can someone explain me how Google api works? I read the documentations but it's complicated.

My client does not wish to share calendar as public or give emailId password, and says it is possible to fetch events. I don't think it's possible but I am looking for an answer from experienced person.

Answer (score 0):

Your client is correct. You need to read about service accounts at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount